# Hold and Continue functionality using Android SIP

Tags: android, sip

I am developing a VoIP Android Application using the default Android SIP stack. I am able to make and receive and even hold calls correctly. My problem is when I use the built in hold function `holdCall` provided by `SipAudioCall` class and then resume the call using `continueCall` there is no sound whatsoever between the two phones. I have monitored the logs and made sure that the `AudioGroup` created when the call starts is setting its mode correctly i.e. when held the AudioGroup sets its mode to 0 (MODE_ON_HOLD) and when resumed it sets its mode to 3 (MODE_ECHO_SUPPRESSION). I have even tried to toggle the mute after resuming the call but still no audio whatsoever.

Comment: Is remote party resumed? I mean, do you know if both user agents are in the proper state?

Comment: Yes the remote party is resumed, because the SIP server I am connecting to sends a hold signal to the remote party (the other phone I am calling from) and I hear the "holding tune" and when I resume, the tune stops and the phone says "connected".

Comment: Maybe you can connect your phone to a local WiFi and take a capture to check that you receive audio packets.

Comment: So I'm back working on this project and was able to take captures of the android client I'm working based on the default Android SIP stack and another free SIP client based on pjsip. The main difference is that the pjsip client sends RTCP packages ( Goodbye and SourceDescription packages to be specific) when the hold function is called, whereas the Android SIP implementation doesn't.
This is the only difference between the two, and I think its the reason the other client maintains audio when resuming the held call.

Comment: Just for the record, there is another difference between the packets sent by the Android SIP stack and other SIP stacks. When a connection is established the other SIP stacks send a SIP PRACK packet whereas the default Android stack doesn't.